# How to integrate pie chart using echarts in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pie-chart, echarts

I want to integrate apache echarts in vue js.
So written following code

```
<template>
    <v-chart class="chart" :option="option" />
</template>

<script>
import { use } from "echarts/core";
import { CanvasRenderer } from "echarts/renderers";
import { PieChart } from "echarts/charts";
import { TitleComponent, TooltipComponent, LegendComponent } 
from "echarts/components";
import VChart, { THEME_KEY } from "vue-echarts";

use([
    CanvasRenderer,
    PieChart,
    TitleComponent,
    TooltipComponent,
    LegendComponent
]);

export default {
    name: "ob-donut",
    components: {
        VChart
    },
    inject: {
        [THEME_KEY]: "dark"
    },
    data() {
        return {
            option: {
                title: {
                    text: "Traffic Sources",
                    left: "center"
                },
                tooltip: {
                    trigger: "item",
                    formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)"
                },
                legend: {
                    orient: "vertical",
                    left: "left",
                    data: [
                        "Direct",
                        "Email",
                        "Ad Networks",
                        "Video Ads",
                        "Search Engines"
                    ]
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Traffic Sources",
                    type: "pie",
                    radius: "55%",
                    center: ["50%", "60%"],
                    data: [
                        { value: 335, name: "Direct" },
                        { value: 310, name: "Email" },
                        { value: 234, name: "Ad Networks" },
                        { value: 135, name: "Video Ads" },
                        { value: 1548, name: "Search Engines" }
                    ],
                    emphasis: {
                        itemStyle: {
                            shadowBlur: 10,
                            shadowOffsetX: 0,
                            shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Here are the packages in my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^3.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.23.3",
    "echarts": "^5.4.2",
    "echarts-liquidfill": "^3.1.0",
    "fabric": "^4.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.7.570",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-chartjs": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-echarts": "^6.5.4",
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
}
```

I have defined echarts in app.js file

import VueECharts from "vue-echarts";
Vue.component("v-chart", VueECharts)

But I am getting below errors

```
[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
[Vue warn]: Error in setup: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'proxy')"

found in

---> <Echarts>

[Vue warn]: globally imported h() can only be invoked when there is an active component instance, e.g. synchronously in a component's render or setup function.

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '$vnode')"

found in

---> <Echarts>
```

I am not able to integrate chart in my app

Thanks